# Dynamic dropdown is not coming

Tags: jsf

While selecting a dropdown,the second drop down values are not coming properly.I am attaching the code here
xhtml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"    
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
   <h:head>

   <f:event listener="#{userData.handleEvent}" type="preRenderView" />  
   </h:head>
   <h:body>
 <f:view>
<h:form >
<table>
<tr>
<td> <h:messages showDetail="true" /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><h:outputText value="Enter name : "/></td>
<td><h:inputText value="#{userData.clientname}"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><h:outputText value="Enter Id : " /></td>
<td><h:inputText value="#{userData.id}" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><h:commandButton value="Insert" action="#{userData.add}"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td>#{userData.data}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><h:selectOneRadio value="#{authorData.favColor1}" id="div2">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Red" itemLabel="Color1 - Red" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Green" itemLabel="Color1 - Green"/>
    <f:ajax event="click" binding="valbinding"  execute="@form" render=":div1" listener="#{authorData.setchangeval}"/>
</h:selectOneRadio></td>
</tr>
</table>
</h:form>

<h:panelGroup id="div1" style="display: #{authorData.valdisplay};">
<span>
You have selected #{authorData.message}
</span>
</h:panelGroup>
</f:view>

    <br/>
             <h:outputLabel value="Choose your Car: *&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" for="firstdropdwn" />
             <h:selectOneMenu id="firstdropdwn" value="#{authorData.favoriteCar2}">

                <f:selectItems value="#{authorData.car4List}" var="d" 
                 itemLabel="#{d.carlabel}" itemValue="#{d.carvalue}"/>
                 <f:ajax event="click" binding="valbinding1"  execute="@this firstdropdwn" render=":seconddrpdown" listener="#{authorData.setDropDwnVal}"/>

             </h:selectOneMenu>
    <br/>  

    <h:outputLabel value="Choose your Owner: *&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" for="seconddrpdown" />      
             <h:selectOneMenu id="seconddrpdown" value="">

                <f:selectItems value="#{authorData.car3List}" var="c"
                    itemLabel="#{c.carlabel}" itemValue="#{c.carvalue}"/>

             </h:selectOneMenu>

   </h:body>
</html>
```

Author.java:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;
import javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent;

@ManagedBean(name = "authorData", eager = true)
@SessionScoped
public class Author implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String clientname;
    String id;
    String favColor1;
    public String favoriteCar2;

    private UIComponent valbinding;
    private UIComponent valbinding1;
    public List<Car> car3List;
    /*public Car[] getFavoriteCar3Value()

        {

            car3List = new Car[3];
            car3List[0] = new Car("BMW Series 4 - 316", "316");
            car3List[1] = new Car("BMW Series 4 - 318", "318");
            car3List[2] = new Car("BMW Series 4 - 320", "320");



            return car3List;

        }
   */

    public List<Car> getCar3List() {
        return car3List;
    }

    public void setCar3List(List<Car> car) {
        this.car3List = car;
    }


    public List<Car> car4List;





    public List<Car> getCar4List() {

        car4List = new ArrayList<Car>();
        car4List.add(new Car("BMW","116"));
        car4List.add(new Car("AUDI","118"));
        car4List.add(new Car("MERCEDES","120"));
        return car4List;
    }



    public UIComponent getValbinding1() {
        return valbinding1;
    }






    public void setValbinding1(UIComponent valbinding1) {
        this.valbinding1 = valbinding1;
    }
    private String valdisplay="none";

    private String message;

    public String getFavoriteCar2() {
        return favoriteCar2;
    }






    public void setFavoriteCar2(String favoriteCar2) {
        this.favoriteCar2 = favoriteCar2;
    }
    private static Map<String, String> favoriteCar2Value;

        static

        {

            favoriteCar2Value = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
            favoriteCar2Value.put("BMW Series 1 - 116", "116"); //label, value
            favoriteCar2Value.put("BMW Series 1 - 118", "118");
            favoriteCar2Value.put("BMW Series 1 - 120", "120");

        }

       public Map<String, String> getFavoriteCar2Value()
       {
           return favoriteCar2Value;

       }






    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public String getValdisplay() {
        return valdisplay;
    }
    public void setValdisplay(String valdisplay) {
        this.valdisplay = valdisplay;
    }
    public UIComponent getValbinding() {
        return valbinding;
    }
    public void setValbinding(UIComponent valbinding) {
        this.valbinding = valbinding;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getClientname() {
        return clientname;
    }
    public void setClientname(String clientname) {
        this.clientname = clientname;
    }


    public String getFavColor1() {
        return favColor1;
    }
    public void setFavColor1(String favColor1) {
        this.favColor1 = favColor1;
    }
    public void setchangeval(AjaxBehaviorEvent e){
        this.setValdisplay("none");
        if(this.getFavColor1().equalsIgnoreCase("red")){
          this.setValdisplay("block");
          this.setMessage("RED");
        }else if(this.getFavColor1().equalsIgnoreCase("Green")){
            this.setValdisplay("block");
            this.setMessage("GREEN");
        }

    }

    public void setDropDwnVal(AjaxBehaviorEvent e){

        if(this.getFavoriteCar2().equalsIgnoreCase("116")){
            LinkedList<Car> ob = new LinkedList<Car>();
            ob.add(new Car("Aife","0"));
            ob.add(new Car("Anirban","1"));
            this.setCar3List(ob);

        }else {

            LinkedList<Car> ob1 = new LinkedList<Car>();
            ob1.add(new Car("Saife","0"));
            ob1.add(new Car("Abid","1"));
            this.setCar3List(ob1);

        }

    }


}
```

Car.java:

```
import java.io.Serializable;


public class Car implements Serializable {
    public String carlabel;
    public String carvalue;
    public Car(String carLabel, String carValue) {
        this.carlabel=carLabel;
        this.carvalue=carValue;

    }
    public String getCarlabel() {
        return carlabel;
    }
    public void setCarlabel(String carlabel) {
        this.carlabel = carlabel;
    }
    public String getCarvalue() {
        return carvalue;
    }
    public void setCarvalue(String carvalue) {
        this.carvalue = carvalue;
    }

}
```

The second dropdown down is not coming properly.In listener method of first dropdown the value from first drop down is not 116/118/120.
***The dbms portion is to be ignored.I had put it for another implementation.

Comment: Are you familiar with basic HTML? If not, then I recommend taking time apart to learn some basic HTML first on http://htmldog.com/guides/html, particularly HTML forms. With some basic HTML knowledge, you'd easily have spotted your mistake by just inspecting the JSF-generated HTML output. It's then a matter of altering the JSF source code in such way that it generates exactly the desired HTML output.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to spot several problems.

1. You closed your `h:form` just after the group of radio buttons, but continued to put other elements outside the form. Similarly, your `f:view` is closed right after the panel group, yet other form elements appear after this one. Just move the closing tags for your `h:form` and `f:view` right after closing tag of the last `h:selectOneMenu` (in this order), this should fix one part of your problem.
2. Both of your `f:ajax` are bound to `click`, change this to `change`, otherwise actions are performed even when user, for example, just opens the dropdown.
3. Both of your `f:ajax` have `render` defined as something starting with colon - I had to remove the colon, otherwise the elements were not found.
4. The "Choose your owner" dropdown's `value` is bound to an empty string, which is not correct. Change this to `value="#{authorData.favoriteCar2}"`.
5. The method `Author.getCar4List()` creates a new list each time it is called. Consider keeping only `return car4List;` there and moving the creation to a separate method, annotated with `@PostConstruct` so that it is only called once:

   ```
   @PostConstruct
   private void init() {
       car4List = new ArrayList<Car>();
       car4List.add(new Car("BMW", "116"));
       car4List.add(new Car("AUDI", "118"));
       car4List.add(new Car("MERCEDES", "120"));
   }
   ```

I hope these are all the changes I made, cannot recall there would be anything else needed.

`userData` definition was not part of the code you shared here, so I had to replace some of these references with `authorData` and remove few of them, but that should not have much impact to the things mentioned above.

Comment: Glad it worked. Please mark your question as answered to make it easier to find for others with the same issue. Thanks!